# Are there any good J2EE value list handler pattern implementations?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

Are there any good [value list handler](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/ValueListHandler.html) implementations available?

I've found [valuelist](http://valuelist.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to be stagnating... besides I really need good control of links the taglib generates, because I need to call some JavaScript from it.

Currently I solve it by rewriting the taglib in freemarker and using valuelist's backend.

Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 2):

[Core J2EE Patterns 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131422464) recommends implementing this pattern using a wrapper for [javax.sql.RowSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html). The RowSet allows for a disconnected, scrollable ResultSet. Sun provides a tutorial for the RowSet in [chapter 5](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/chapter5.html) of the JDBC Tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

We've had good luck with [Display Tag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/)